# Getting jquery to delay after adding a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a script to halt before continuing after adding a class, below are two attempts that seem to fail.

```
 window.setTimeout($("#"+item).addClass("highlight"), 5000 );

 $("#"+item).addClass("highlight").delay(5000);
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: What do you want to do after the halt?

Comment: jqt.goto - jqtouch animation. At the moment you hit a button and the screen scrolls, doesn't show you have highlighted the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way:

```
$("#"+item).addClass("highlight");

setTimeout(function(){
//rest of the code
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
function addClassAndDelay(item, nextMenu) {
    $("#"+item).addClass("highlight");
    window.setTimeout(function() { restOfCode(nextMenu); }, 5000);
}

function restOfCode(nextMenu) {
    jQT.goTo('#'+nextMenu, 'slide');
}
```

Comment: tried...                                                                   `function addClassAndDelay(item, nextMenu) {
    $("#"+item).addClass("highlight");
    window.setTimeout(restOfCode(nextMenu), 5000);
}                                                                                    problem persists

function restOfCode(nextMenu) {
   jQT.goTo('#'+nextMenu, 'slide');
}`

Comment: @maxum I've updated it so it should work with your example. As you're passing a variable on to restOfCode, it needs to be called in an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for the [jQuery Highlight](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight) plugin?

```
$("#mydiv").click(function () {
      $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```